# Using Angular.js for a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, npm

So I've been using knockout.js to do the data-binding for a particular chrome extension I am working on.  I've thought that it may make sense to move to a framework (like Angular).  After using npm to install all of the dependencies for my angular, the node_module folder is over 100 MB.  This is obviously too large to contain in the chrome extension, and have installed on each users machine.  Any recommendations on how I should go about using Angular for my extension in such a way that it doesn't require hundreds of MB of files on the client's machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to include **bower_components** or **node_modules** folder in your Chrome Extension. Try using Grunt/Gulp for minification.

Your Repository should ideally contain a **dist** folder, which contains the production ready state of your extension. When you're uploading your extension to the Chrome Webstore, you should create a ZIP of this folder.

Use the below Grunt plugins for optimizing your application,

[grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) - will extract all your stylesheets or scripts from index.html, and combine them into a single CSS or JS file, so you do not have to worry about the node_modules or bower_components folder.

[grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) - will uglify/minify the JS file.

In short, treat your Chrome Extension as any real world production Angular application, which will normally contain a distribution folder containing the optimized version of your code. You will be deploying the contents in this folder to production, and not the entire repository.

You can refer a Chrome Extension, which I have worked on, named **Browser Automation Tookit** on Github. You can check **Gruntfile.js** and the **dist** folder for further guidance.

https://github.com/kensplanet/browser-automation-toolkit

Comment: @kensplanet is there any reason to use grunt over gulp with chrome extension? what do you think?

Comment: @NikitaChernykh No there is no special reason to use Grunt over Gulp in Angular 1.xxx. If you are using Angular 4, Webpack is supported by default.

Comment: Great tnx, using gulp now. Thanks:

Answer (score 0):

When you use npm for client-side dependencies you should only include the dist files. (Angular for instance - /node_modules/angular/angular.js)

Usually those files only weight few kb.
It's better to use the package minified version in production if they expose such (/node_modules/angular/angular**.min**.js) or minify it by your self you can use any task runner for it (grunt/gulp)

Furthermore, I will highly recommend you not to reinvent the wheel and start with a yeoman genrator or a project seed like: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension